# Cual es la configuración de un dominio por defecto sin Virtual Host? Digital Ocean

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, apache, virtualhost

Tenemos un sitio web heredado y alojado en digital ocean, y se encuentra en la ruta /home/admin/web/dominio/public_html, queremos configurar un certificado ssl pero nos obliga a configurar un virtual host el cuál no sabemos donde se encuentra, probamos buscar en /etc/apache2/sites-avaible/000-default.conf pero no hay nada configurado en tal archivo. 
¿Hay alguna configuracion del sitio web por defecto que no requiera configurar virtual hosts?
Es un proyecto Laravel.

Comment: debe tener un virtualhost , probablemente no se llame `000-default.conf ` busca en esa misma carpeta las configuraciones cargdas

Comment: Podrias ejecutar este comando: **apache2ctl -S** y compartir lo que te devuelve